# How to avoid running a deadly function 30,000 times in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have two lists of identical length. I want to check conditions in one list. If the conditions are true then run a very memory/processing intensive function on the other list.

My first attempt was as so:

```
records = [(a, deadly_func(b)) for a, b in zip(listA, listB) if a == "condition"]
```

This immediately allocated all the memory on my desktop and went on for a while before I killed it. Evidently, it ran deadly_func(b) on all 30,000 items in listB, whereas the intention was to use the 'if' statement to filter listB down to about 30 items.

I was able to make a working version with:

```
records = [(a, i) for a, i in zip(listA, range(len(listB)) if a == "condition"]
records = [(a, deadly_func(listB[i]) for a, i in records]
```

Why did my first attempt not work? Is there a more pythonic way to make this work?

---

Edit: Thank you for the responses. Here is the actual code for both versions

Did not work:

```
import shapefile, shapely.geometry as shpgeo

lat = 42.3968243
lon = -71.0313479

sf = shapefile.Reader("/opt/ziplfs/tl_2014_us_zcta510.shp")

records = [(r[0], shpgeo.shape(s.__geo_interface__)) for r, s in zip(sf.records(), sf.shapes()) if haversine(lon, lat, float(r[8]), float(r[7])) < 10]
```

haversine() is a user-made haversine function, taking two pairs of lat and long and returns a distance in km.

```
from math import sqrt, sin, cos, radians, asin
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees). Return is in kilometers
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
```

The shapefile ('tl_2014_us_zcta510.shp') is all zipcodes in the US, from the Census Bureau. Download [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2014-2010-nation-u-s-2010-census-5-digit-zip-code-tabulation-area-zcta5-na) if you really love shapefiles, and have 800 MB on your hard drive you don't know what to do with.

This script should return a list of tuples representing all zipcodes in the US with a centroid within 10 km of Chelsea, MA.

For the working version, replace the records line with:

```
records = [(r[0], i) for r, i in zip(sf.records(), range(len(sf.records()))) if haversine(lon, lat, float(r[8]), float(r[7])) < 10]
shapes = [shpgeo.shape(sf.shape(i).__geo_interface__) for r, i in records]
```

I did some timing tests. The 'non-working' version:

```
$ python test.py 
Time Elapsed: 0:00:14.221533
$ python test.py 
Time Elapsed: 0:00:14.637827
$ python test.py 
Time Elapsed: 0:00:14.253425
```

and the working version:

```
$ python test.py 
Time Elapsed: 0:00:01.887987
$ python test.py 
Time Elapsed: 0:00:01.886635
$ python test.py 
Time Elapsed: 0:00:01.982547
```

Maybe not 'deadly' per say, but significant when you repeat 30k times.

Comment: Why would you want to run a deadly function even once?

Comment: @JohnColeman lets say the function is deadly only if `a != "condition"` :)

Comment: Do you have an example of the kind of lists involved? I just tried replicating this using `print` and some small containers, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Could you provide a more clear example we can execute? The first case should not be running 30000 times. The `if` condition is examined before the call is made.

Comment: First thing I would do is use `itertools.izip` iterator instead of `zip` which does this in one go.

Comment: @bulbus Note that this is Python 3. `itertools.izip` doesn't exist anymore (because `zip` does return an iterator).

Comment: Ah, ok. Thx for clarifying @smarx

Comment: Clearly there is trouble in the `if` condition. To test it reverse the condition and it should run `zero` times. If so then your code is fine, but your condition is wrong.

Comment: Quick question: Does `deadly_func` reference `records` itself, and does `records` exist before the listcomp (essentially, are you generating a new `records` to replace an existing one)? The only way I can see the two forms of your code differing is if `deadly_func` is performing work relative to every other entry in `records`, and therefore in the first case, it's running against the previous contents of `records`, while in the second case, it's running against a pared down `records` from the first listcomp.

Comment: Of course, even then, I'd assume previous `records` was always pared, so it seems unlikely...

Comment: @ShadowRanger I updated with more actual code. deadly_func is actually shapely.geometry.shape() which takes a shapefile.Shape object. So, no, deadly_func has nothing to do with records.

Comment: @bulbus the 'if' condition is identical in the working and non-working versions. There is a ~factor of 10 run time difference between the two that I do not understand.

Comment: The difference is almost certainly the difference between computing all the `sf.shapes()` and computing only the `sf.shape(i)` for the records that pass your filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No repro? This code does *not* run `deadly_func` on all the elements of `listB`. Just the ones where the corresponding `listA` value is `True`:

```
listA = [True, False, True, False]
listB = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def deadly_func(x):
    print("Called with {}".format(x))
    return x

print([(a, deadly_func(b)) for a, b in zip(listA, listB) if a])

# Output:
# Called with 1
# Called with 3
# [(True, 1), (True, 3)]
```

**EDIT**

Based on the updated question, my guess is that `sf.shapes()` is the expensive part. Thus calling `sf.shape(i)` on only the subset of elements you want is more efficient.

If my guess is correct, this should do the trick:

```
records = [(r[0], shpgeo.shape(sf.shape(i).__geo_interface__)) for i, r in enumerate(sf.records()) if haversine(lon, lat, float(r[8]), float(r[7])) < 10]
```

(Of course, this is mostly what you already did.)

Comment: BTW, I realize this isn't really an answer to the question... but it's hard to share code without posting an answer. I'll happily delete this once the original issue is clarified.

Comment: I think that it is fine as an answer. It does *partially* answer the question in that it tells OP that their hypothesis that the first code runs it 30,000 times is mistaken. That is important to show, so +1.

Comment: Yes, thank you for demonstrating that the function is not being run so many times. I will update the original question with the actual code, but it involves an 800 MB US Census bureau shapefile, so it is not immediately replicable.

Comment: `for i, r in enumerate(sf.records())`

Comment: @smarx That was the trick! This is basically what I did in two lines, but I didn't make the connection that throwing allocating all the shapes in sf into memory then iterating through them was causing the problems. Thank you.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks for that tip. Dropped the run time from ~1.9 secs to ~1.0 secs with enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble with a list comprehension, sometimes it is easier to deconstruct it down to its `for loop` equivalent.

Such as:

```
things = []

for a, b in zip(listA, listB):
    if a == "condition":
        things.append(a, deadly_func(b))
```

It would be helpful to see your input/output. This isn't a full answer, but might help you debug your code.

Also, you can reduce the size of your input to the first 1000 for debugging by adding:

```
for a, b, in zip(listA, listB)[:1000]:
....
```

Comment: Your "reduce the input" suggestion is wrong; this is Py3, and `zip` returns a generator, not a `list`. You could either slice one of the `list`s it operates on `zip(listA[:1000], listB)`, or to handle arbitrary iterable inputs, use `itertools.islice` (on either `zip` object or either input): `islice(zip(listA, listB), 1000)`